# derived classes & type checking

Tags: c++, overloading, typechecking, typeid

I'm trying to write a method that takes a class derived from std::string as an argument.  The method is overloaded with several different function signatures.  I'd like compilation to fail if I try to call it with a std::string, or at the very least a runtime error but apparently the compiler is too smart for me.

```
class NotAString : public std::string {
    NotAString(std::string str) : std::string(str) { }
};


class Foo {
   Foo();
   void bar(NotAString);
   void bar(int)
};
```

This compiles and runs

```
Foo foo();
foo.bar(NotAString("baz"));
```

But so does this:

```
Foo foo();
foo.bar(std::string("baz"));
```

I've tried using typeid(str) like so:

```
void Foo::Bar(NotAString str) {
    if(typeid(&str) != typeid(new NotAString()) {
        throw std::bad_typeid();
    }
}
```

But it always throws an exception if a pass it a std::string or NotAString.  I've tried using a dynamic_cast like so:

```
void Foo::Bar(NotAString str) {
    if (dynamic_cast<NotAString*>(&str) == NULL) {
        throw std::bad_type();
    }
}
```

But it never throws an exception.

The goal is to be able to differentiate between a string and a string that represents a key for a key-value lookup.  How can I change my NotAString class or enforce some more rigorous type checking by the compiler to get this to work how I would like?

Comment: Deriving from `std::string` is a bad idea.

Comment: `NotAString` is a `std::string`. So you have a class, which is, by it's own name, not a string, but is a string. I'm going to drink something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `NotAString(std::string str)` constuctor is not [`explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean) so it allows implicit conversions from `std::string` to `NotAString`.

When you call the function with a `std::string` the compiler notices that you could call it by converting the argument via the constructor, so it creates a `NotAString` temporary and passes it to the function.

If you declare it `explicit NotAString(std::string str)` then it won't allow those implicit conversions.

Your attempts to check the type *inside* the function are never going to work, by that point the compiler has create a `NotAString` and all you're testing is whether a `NotAString` argument is not a `NotAString` ... which is obviously not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Bad design ideas aside, change this constructor...

```
class NotAString : public std::string {
    NotAString(std::string str) : std::string(str) { }
};
```

...to be `explicit`:

```
class NotAString : public std::string {
    explicit NotAString(std::string str) : std::string(str) { }
};
```

That will prevent `std::string` objects from implcitly being converted to `NotAString` when they are used as a function parameter.